# Access graphic card clock programmatically

Tags: .net, windows, kernel, clock, interrupt

**Is it possible to use graphic card clock from a windows application?** More specifically - is it possible to somehow make graphic card to send interrupts on clock events (tick?) and hook to it from a software?

What I am trying to say is that PC clocks arent good. precision clocks cost a lot of money plus they are difficult when it comes to colo (GPS signal is not available and atomic clocks cost an arm and a leg and more). I read that new graphic cards have precision clocks on them. So my immediate thought - can I use them to sync my app with precision down to 100ns perhaps *(mental note to myself)*? any ideas?

P.S. Or audio card on that matter...
P.P.S. PLEASE answer the question - can I hook up to a graphic/audio card internal clock, not the windows vs linux discussion. thank you

Comment: BTW: HPET or PMTIMER were the answers to the question you should have asked.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer

Comment: This question comes up continuously. You have to write a driver to hook-up interrupts. To get the event in a user-mode app you first have to have to transfer the control from the interrupt handler to a kernel thread and then signal the user-mode thread. Because every (non) interrupt can be interrupted (and in a general purpose OS it will be). Most of the time, it won't be interrupted, and you can claim 'yeah it works' but sometimes, the zero-page-thread kicks in or the cache manager pages something out and latency soares and all your nice ideas about synching to a stable event fail.

Comment: @BenVoigt sorry I still disagree. the problem with the PC clock is not precision but drift. @ Chris - thanks

Comment: @Bobb: In your other question, you said "drift is fine".  Before asking for 16 parts per trillion linearity.  Sorry, you can't buy an IC with that kind of tolerance, you need an atomic clock for that.  Graphics cards definitely are nowhere near that tolerance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot *"use them to sync my app with precision down to 100ns perhaps"*.  Interrupt processing jitter can be greater than 100ns.  You'd need to use the very highest-priority interrupt and never let interrupts be disabled.

Then you want this in .NET?  Non-deterministic garbage collection and precision timing just aren't compatible.  Pick a platform more suited to your requirements.

Comment: Ben I know the argument of the windows is no good for real-time and all... I have an app which works faster than most think it can and doesnt use GC. so please keep to the point... you misunderstood the 100ns figure. I dont want my app to be synced with precision of 100ns, I want to have a source of sync better than I have now. May be not 100ns but 250ns. You can always measure statistically jitter and subtract it when syncing etc....

Comment: @Bobb: jitter is not the same as latency.  And yes, I know the tricks by which .NET apps can meet deadlines which are maybe 100 microseconds or so, but you're asking for three orders of magnitude better.

Comment: No all I am asking is a precision clock. please dont extend your assumptions further to my applicaiton. it could be anything. not just mine. other people might use solution if it exists and dont pay gazillions for the same but in a bigger box. thanks.

Comment: @Bobb: The answer is still the same.  You can't precisely sync the CPU using an interrupt if the interrupt delivery includes jitter.

Comment: I am sorry Ben the question is can I access clock on internal cards easily and cheaply sourced for public ie graphic or audio card.

Comment: @Bobb: What's with the mention of linux?  By "pick a platform more suited to your requirements" I meant a microcontroller, not a different general-purpose OS that suffers from all the same interrupt jitter problems.