# Audio/graphic card as a cheap precision clock

Tags: windows, optimization, clock

I understand that modern audio/graphic cards have precision clocks on board and I guess they are superior to a generic PC clock.

Is it possible to use audio or graphic card internal clock as a precision clock on Windows? Receive events/interrupts in a Windows application for the card in question?

**EDIT** Inspired by Hans's comment I want to clarify. Although I do have not bad sync in place it is very far from ideal. Using network for time precision is the last think I want. this is why I want to use some internal clock which is **stable**. Stable is key word here. Although Ben suggests that PC clocks are fine they are not. Drift is enormous. Under load W2K 8 threads Xeon can bounce easily 30ms up and down in just few seconds. Stability is a paramount, not resolution of the clock. I just guess any decent stable clock will have better resolution than 1ms - the one I have from Stratum 2. Let me reiterate - **ultimately I need a clock with 1ns per 1 min drift and at least 250us resolution** (for £100-150! if you please) :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040967/access-graphic-card-clock-programmatically

Comment: No, opposite goals.  A sound card oscillator needs to be stable but doesn't have to be accurate.  The PC clock needs to be accurate.  And gets help from a time service to drift no more than a second over an entire year.  No better precision is available until you reach for custom hardware (GPS radios).  Resolution is not great however.

Comment: For what it's worth, your PC has a number of clocks far more precise than either graphics or sound card.  For example, the PCI express bus clock is 100MHz.  USB HS is 480MHz.  SATA3 is 6GHz.  Even a fancy sound card is only 192kHz.  Video pixel clock is faster, but not by much, often about 50 MHz.

Comment: @HansPassant. Drift is fine. I can re-sync this with external clock and have 2 layers of syncing - internal which is stable as you said but drifting away (and do it every 1s) and external which I can use to adjuts the internal adjustments (if you know what I mean)

Comment: That makes very little sense, you are using the "external clock" to provide the precision.  Just use that external clock then.  You must have a different definition of precision than the common meaning.

Comment: No thats exactly what I am looking - in your first answer. the external is going over ethernet and it is nntp. the stability is way way worse than you can achieve if you have not precise but stable internal clock...... so I am defo interested in both - internal for stability and external for nudging the internal once in a while

Comment: @Bobb: I think you are conflating *precision* with *accuracy*.

Comment: You're asking for drift less than 16 parts per trillion?  Not happening, not for any reasonable cost.

Comment: HPET discussion, btw: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=59628

Comment: Why are you asking for this level of precision when you're not even running a RTOS?

Comment: @user57368 thanks for the downvote. sure you know better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No electronics have 1ns/min tolerance.

Here's the best I could find:

- http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/AOCJY-10.000MHZ/535-10099-ND/2089872

Its drift is 5ns/sec, which is 300 times worse that what you're asking for.  And already at the upper limit of your price range.  And doesn't include any of the support/interfacing circuitry to make it work with your computer.

You need something much pricier to do better.

Comment: Thanks. this is something to look into. I wonder if anyone makes boards with this clock.

Answer (score 1):

Windows applications can't receive interrupts, only kernel mode drivers can.  The kernel mode driver can generate an event that wakes or otherwise triggers the application, but there'll be added delay, making it no better as a timer than the PC timer / scheduler quantum.

I suppose you're asking whether any of the vendor drivers provide timing information to applications?  I don't know that there's no way at all, but there's no standardized way to that would be reasonably portable across hardware models (at least with better precision than your frame rate, which is much *worse* than the PC timer / scheduler quantum).

Comment: may be you are right and I am just being stupid... lets keep it open for a day. may be someone has some tricky solution. real question is how to _improve syncing which is now done at 10 sec intervals and shows 1-2ms drift and uses external server in local network (which is far worse than any audio card).

Comment: @Bobb: Well, you can absolutely bump up (down?) to 10 ms intervals, just using the normal OS clock, based on your computer's HPET.

Comment: I tried to explain what I need better in the edit of the main post.

Comment: @Bobb: Not all APIs will read from the HPET, some will use the old unreliable PC-XT timer system.  So it matters what OS functions you use, but the OS already provides everything you need.